# Alterando telas no Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragment, navigation-drawer

O [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) teve algumas alterações, onde era usado o método `onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long itemId)` e agora vem com o método 
`onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)`.

Tentei implementar o modelo antigo, para fazer a chamada de meus fragments, mas não consegui, talvez seja pela minha pouco experiencia com Android.

Alguém poderia me ajudar como posso fazer a chamada de meus fragments com esse novo método que vem implementado no [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

```
package com.example.junior.fireflyapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class ActListarOpcoes extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_listar_opcoes);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.act_listar_opcoes, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_buscar){


        }else if (id == R.id.nav_criarEvento) {


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_sair) {

            finish();

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Segue imagem de como está meu menu lateral, caso ajude em algo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Olá, eu faço dessa forma:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.****:
            abraSeuFragment;
            break;
        case R.id.****:
            abraseuFragment;
            break;
    return true;
}
```

Para abrir seu Fragment utilize o seguinte:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Mais informações sobre fragments, vc pode ver na [documentação oficial](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Espero ter ajudado!!!

Comment: Arubu..postei um problema que estou tendo, se puder me dar um help eu agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

### Para chamar uma nova Activity(Atividade):

Crie uma nova `Activity` com o nome de `MainActivity2` e insira este código abaixo em seu método `onNavigationItemSelected`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class); 
startActivity(intent);
```

---

### Para chamar um novo Fragment(Fragmento):

Crie um novo `Fragment` com o nome de `novoFragment` e insira este código abaixo em seu método `onNavigationItemSelected`:

```
novoFragment fragment = new novoFragment();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTrasaction =
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTrasaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTrasaction.commit();
```

### ** Aviso Importante **

Para que a chamada deste `fragment` se conclua com sucesso (funcione), é necessário seguir este post mais completo sobre o assunto: [Menu de 3 pontos em todas as Activities com o padrão Navigation Drawer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119551/navigation-drawer-em-todas-as-telas/119561)

---

### Solução na prática

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // abrindo um novo fragment
     novoFragment fragment = new novoFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTrasaction =
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTrasaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTrasaction.commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery)  {
    // abrindo um nova activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class); 
    startActivity(intent);    
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```