# Menu de 3 pontos em todas as Activities com o padrão Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Estou começando agora a implementar em Android.

Estou com uma pequena dúvida, criei uma Blank Activity (activity_inicial) e com ela a Action Bar, depois criei um Navigation Drawer (navigation_menu) também normal, sem nada.

Quero saber como faço pra que em todas as Activities apareça o menu de 3 pontos com o menu lateral da Navigation Drawer?

Comment: Você está utilizando o android studio? Ele te ajuda bastante nessa parte na hora da criação de um projeto com Navigation Drawer.

Answer (score 7):

Se bem entendi, tu queres colocar a NavigationDrawer e o correspondente icon (icon das 3 linhas) acessivel em todas as tuas actividades.

Se queres mesmo fazer isso tens de replicar a lógica da tua BlankActivity em todas as novas actividades que criares, ou seja no ficheiro .xml de cada activity tens de adicionar a NavigationDrawer.

No entanto não te aconselho a fazeres isso. Isso é má prática e vai gerar confusão na navegação entre as actividades.

O que eu sugiro é que tenhas a NavigationDrawer na tua BlankActivity e uses fragments para mostrares os diferentes ecrãs correspondentes ás diferentes entradas do menu da NavigationDrawer.

Comment: Exatamente isso!

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**

O Menu de itens(três pontos) na `Action Bar` de seu App, geralmente é usado como menu de Opções, Configurações ou Sobre.

Implementando projeto padrão Navigation Drawer:

---

### Implementando o método - onCreateOptionsMenu

Primeiro você precisa implementar o método `onCreateOptionsMenu` em seu arquivo `MainActivity.java`, dessa maneira:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {    
 // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.    
 getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);    
 return true;    
}
```

### Criando o arquivo - main.xml

Agora edite ou crie um arquivo (se não existir) na pasta "menu", chamado de `main.xml`, com o seguinte código:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_about"
    android:title="@string/about"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

### Adicionando uma String Name - about

Agora adicione uma string *name* chamada "about", com o nome "Sobre", lá na pasta "values" em `strings.xml`, dessa maneira:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Novo App</string>
    <string name="about">Sobre</string>
</resources>
```

Agora é só teclar <kbd>CTRL+S</kbd> e depois <kbd>CTRL+F9</kbd> para ver o resultado.

Você terá apenas um item do menu de `3 Pontos` "Sobre" aparecendo na `Action Bar` pronto para ser "usado", mas você não verá nada acontecendo, perceba que se você clicar sobre ele, não acontecerá nada, até porque você ainda não criou outra tela e nem implementou outro método muito importante, veja a seguir.

### Criando um novo Fragment - sobreFragment

Crie agora um novo `fragment` chamado de `sobreFragment`, dessa maneira:

Clique em cima de seu pacote exemplo: `br.com.app`, com o botão direito do mouse e siga para `New` > `Fragment` > `Fragment(Blank)`

Com a janela `New Android Component` aberta, faça as seguintes alterações:

- Fragment Name: sobreFragment
- Fragment Layout Name: Fragment_sobre

Desmarque as opções:

- Include fragment factory methods?
- Include interface callbacks?

agora clique no botão [Finish] e aguarde enquanto o Android Studio cria o seu novo `fragment`...

### Implementando o método - onOptionsItemSelect

Depois de ter criado o seu novo `fragment`, para abrir uma nova tela (aqui no caso eu usei um `Fragment`), para a sua opção "Sobre" funcionar, você terá que implementar outro método chamado de `onOptionsItemSelect` em seu arquivo `MainActivity.java`, dessa maneira:

```
@Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 int id = item.getItemId();
 if (id == R.id.action_about) {
  sobreFragment fragment = new sobreFragment();
  android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTrasaction =
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  fragmentTrasaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
  fragmentTrasaction.commit();
 }
 return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Veja que acima usei um `id` chamado `fragment_container`, para chamar o `fragment` "sobreFragment" dentro de um outro `fragment` vazio, para assim poder alternar entre as telas.

### Exemplo - Transição entre Telas

Se clico em um item do menu `Navigation Drawer` ou em um item do menu `3 pontos` de minha `Action Bar`, vou ser enviado para determinada tela e se depois clico em outro item, vou para outra tela, por isso o uso de um `fragment` vazio com uma `id` chamada de `@+id/fragment_container` para "armazenar" as telas que preciso ver naquele momento.

Para que não ocorra nenhum erro de implementação em seu método `onOptionsItemSelected`, você precisa de uma nova `Activity`, ou de um novo `fragment` que esteja vazio, para que você possa alternar e "armazenar" determinado `fragment`("tela"), dentro dele.

### "Armazenando Telas - fragment_container"

No meu caso, usei o arquivo `content_main.xml`, que está na pasta `layout` e que estava sem nada, para "armazenar" as minhas "telas"(fragments), como feito abaixo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"        
    android:layout_width="match_parent"        
    android:layout_height="match_parent"        
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"        
    tools:context=".MainActivity"        
    android:background="@android:color/white"        
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <FrameLayout        
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"        
    android:layout_height="match_parent"        
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### Para chamar uma nova Activity(Atividade):

Crie uma nova `Activity` com o nome de `MainActivity2` e insira este código abaixo em seu método `onNavigationItemSelected` de sua `MainActivity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class); 
startActivity(intent);
```

---

### Para chamar um novo Fragment(Fragmento):

Crie um novo `Fragment` com o nome de `sobreFragment` e insira este código abaixo em seu método `onNavigationItemSelected` de sua `MainActivity`:

```
sobreFragment fragment = new sobreFragment();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTrasaction =
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTrasaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTrasaction.commit();
```

---

### Em sua MainActivity - Solução na prática:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // abrindo um novo fragment
     sobreFragment fragment = new sobreFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTrasaction =
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTrasaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTrasaction.commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery)  {
    // abrindo um nova activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class); 
    startActivity(intent);    
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

### ** Aviso importante: **

Se você criou um novo projeto no Android Studio, com uma `Blank Activity` e depois criou um menu `Navigation Drawer`, deve se lembrar de que você deve seguir a ordem de precedência das Activities, perceba que seu app irá iniciar com a tela em branco em primeiro lugar e nada acontecerá, então lembre-se de mudar o seu Arquivo `AndroidManifest.xml` para iniciar com o menu `Navigation Drawer`, ou sempre que possível inicie um projeto direto com o menu `Navigation Drawer` e posteriormente crie as outras Activities(atividades) e os Fragments(fragmentos).

### Arquivo AndroidManifest.xml - Modo "Errado":

Veja abaixo, aplicativo iniciando com a `BlankActivity` ("Modo errado"), supondo que a `Activity` em branco tenha o nome de `.BlankActivity`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.erroapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".BlankActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Obs:** observe que o código acima não está errado, `ele só será considerado errado se você não adicionar nada em sua tela, fazendo com que seu aplicativo inicie sem nada na tela`, veja que para este código acima estar correto você terá que transformar essa `BlankActivity` em uma tela de login, onde ela cadastra/faz login de um usuário e joga para a outra tela de seu app(faz o login e joga o resultado para `MainActivity`), ou transformar ela em uma tela de SplashScreen, como nesse post: [Activity não muda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120161/activity-n%C3%A3o-muda/120182).

Veja a seguir como mudar seu arquivo `AndroidManifest.xml` se esse erro ocorrer...

---

### Arquivo AndroidManifest.xml - Modo Correto:

Veja abaixo, aplicativo iniciando com o menu `Navigation Drawer` (Modo correto), supondo que a `Activity` do menu `Navigation Drawer` tenha o nome de `.MainActivity`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.appcorreto">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".BlankActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Obs:** Observe que o código acima, está correto, partindo do pressuposto que sua `BlankActivity` não tem nada. A sua aplicação inicia com a atividade principal(MainActivity - que contém o menu Navigation Drawer  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`) e a sua `BlankActivity` não interfere em nada, ela fica parada, aguardando ser chamada se for o caso, você pode chamar essa atividade através do menu, como no trecho acima > **Em sua MainActivity - Solução na prática:** < mudando apenas a chamada com o Intent de: `MainActivity2.class` para: `BlankActivity.class`.

---

Tenho um post resposta aqui no StackOverflow, que fala mais sobre este problema de precedência das `Activities`(atividades), acesse: [Activity não muda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120161/activity-n%C3%A3o-muda/120182)

Espero ter ajudado.

---

Comment: Vlw, era isso mesmo que estava tentando fazer.
pela logica acho que ta certo, vou implementar pra vê.