# Activity não muda

Tags: android, android-activity

Sou iniciante em Android e estou criando um app que possui duas atividades (`SplashScreen` e `ActivityMain`).

Consegui fazer aparecer a `SplashScreen` depois de muito sacrifício, porém, quando instalo no dispositivo, aparece a mensagem:

> O ****** parou

Alguém poderia me ajudar?
Abaixo segue o código da `SplashScreen`

```
package bbacpropaganda.microfapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Set waktu lama splashscreen
    private static int splashInterval = 2000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);


//Após alguns segundos vai para atividade principal
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {


            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                //jeda selesai Splashscreen
            }

        }, splashInterval);

//Fim de alguns segundos vai para atividade principal



   }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_splash_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: você pode colocar o erro que aparece no console?? Provavelmente o erro acontece pois você não declarou essa nova activity no manifest.

Comment: Pode ser algum problema no `onCreate` da outra Activity também.

Comment: Lucas e Pablo, obrigadão pela força!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já passei pelo mesmo problema anteriormente, então resolvi ajudar.

Primeiro altere o seu Arquivo AndroidManifest.xml, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.novoapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Perceba que acima, estou usando um Tema meu, então se você copiar o código acima altere para o seu tema.

Perceba também que no código acima estou usando a ordem de precedência, onde a Activity `.SplashScreen` vem em primeiro lugar e demora cerca de 3 segundos para sair da tela, ela inicia em modo `Portrait` e depois passa para a `MainActivity`.

Depois mude o seu arquivo SplashScreen.java, como feito abaixo:

```
package br.com.novoapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;


public class SplashScreen extends Activity{

    // Splash screen timer
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;
    private Typeface type;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }

}
```

Agora crie um novo arquivo chamado de `activity_splash.xml` ou modifique-o para poder exibir essa tela de Splash, que no caso utilizei para exibir uma imagem centralizada, que está contida na pasta `Drawable`, veja no código a seguir:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary" >

   <ImageView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:src="@drawable/telasplash"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="visible"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Perceba que no código acima, coloquei uma imagem centraliza e com uma cor especifica no background, que você pode modificar no arquivo `colors.xml`, que está na pasta `Values`.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado Paulo!
Deu tudo certo.

Vlw mesmo.