# Navigation Drawer sem interação ao ser clicado

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou utilizando o menu do padrão `Navigation Drawer` e complementei o método que já vem no projeto para abrir as minhas `activities(Atividades)`. Já criei as classes e já chamei cada uma delas conforme imagem abaixo, porem quando clico em um item do menu, e ele não faz a mudança de janelas.

[image: erro]

e aqui está uma de minhas classes:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button share;
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private Toolbar mToolbarBottom;
private Button action_settings;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);


    mToolbarBottom = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.inc_tb_bottom);
    mToolbarBottom.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            Intent it = null;

            switch(menuItem.getItemId()){
                case R.id.action_facebook:
                    it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    it.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/PrefeituraMunicipalDeJaguaruana"));
                    break;
                case R.id.action_youtube:
                    it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    it.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.jaguaruana.ce.gov.br/"));

            }

            startActivity(it);
            return true;
        }
    });
    mToolbarBottom.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_bottom);

    /*mToolbarBottom.findViewById(R.id.iv_settings).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "Settings pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }*/

}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        mToolbar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.toolbar_rounded_corners);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_second, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id == android.R.id.home){
        finish();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: tente mudar para `Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); startActivity(intent);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Para chamar uma nova Activity(Atividade):

Crie uma nova `Activity` com o nome de `MainActivity2` e insira este código abaixo em seu método `onNavigationItemSelected` de sua `MainActivity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class); 
startActivity(intent);
```

---

### Para chamar um novo Fragment(Fragmento):

Crie um novo `Fragment` com o nome de `novoFragment` e insira este código abaixo em seu método `onNavigationItemSelected` de sua `MainActivity`:

```
novoFragment fragment = new novoFragment();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTrasaction =
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTrasaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTrasaction.commit();
```

### ** Aviso Importante **

Para que a chamada deste `fragment` se conclua com sucesso (funcione), é necessário seguir este post mais completo sobre o assunto: [Menu de 3 pontos em todas as Activities com o padrão Navigation Drawer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119551/navigation-drawer-em-todas-as-telas/119561)

---

### Em sua MainActivity - Solução na prática:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // abrindo um novo fragment
     novoFragment fragment = new novoFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTrasaction =
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTrasaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTrasaction.commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery)  {
    // abrindo um nova activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class); 
    startActivity(intent);    
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```