# Telas do menu ficam por cima da tela inicial do aplicativo

Tags: android, android-studio

Estava implementando o padrão Navigation Drawer e quando emulei o apk ficou as telas das opções por cima da tela inicial do apk, desse jeito:

[image: erro]

**Arquivo MainActivity.java**

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_second_activity) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    if (id == R.id.servic) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new Cronograma())
                .commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new Localizacao())
                .commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new Sobre_aplicativo())
                .commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
        finish();

    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

**Meu fragment:**

```
    public class Localizacao  extends Fragment {
    View view;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.local, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Porque esta sobrepondo a outra intent e não mudando?

observei que no código ele me mostra essas mensagens:

[image: erro1]
[image: erro2]

**Arquivo content_main.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Arquivo activity_main_drawer:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/servic"
            android:icon="@drawable/servico"
            android:title="Serviços" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
            android:icon="@drawable/pref"
            android:title="o local" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/local"
            android:title="Localização" />

    </group>

    <item android:title="Informações">
        <menu>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/dev"
                android:title="Sobre o aplicativo" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
                android:icon="@drawable/exit"
                android:title="Sair" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Comment: pelo que estou vendo você colocou uma `listview` junto com um `@id/content_frame` o que está errado! já que você irá usar este arquivo(tela) `content_main.xml` para fazer a transição dos fragments? correto?

Comment: Veja este post, onde ensino a fazer a transição entre telas  http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119551/menu-de-3-pontos-em-todas-as-activities-com-o-padr%C3%A3o-navigation-drawer/119561#119561

Comment: essa sua `listview` deve desaparecer, ou você deve colocar esses itens no menu do padrão Navigation Drawer - em `activity_main_drawer.xml`, ou ainda criar um menu de itens em outro fragment e chamar esse fragment através do `@+id/content_frame` e fazer a transição das telas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Para chamar uma nova Activity(Atividade):

Crie uma nova `Activity` com o nome de `MainActivity2` e insira este código abaixo em seu método `onNavigationItemSelected` de sua `MainActivity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class); 
startActivity(intent);
```

---

### Para chamar um novo Fragment(Fragmento):

Crie um novo `Fragment` com o nome de `novoFragment` e insira este código abaixo em seu método `onNavigationItemSelected` de sua `MainActivity`:

```
novoFragment fragment = new novoFragment();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTrasaction =
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTrasaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTrasaction.commit();
```

### ** Aviso Importante **

> Para que a chamada deste `fragment` se conclua com sucesso (funcione),
>   é necessário criar um novo fragment (`novoFragment`) e fazer uso de outro  `fragment` e que esteja vazio (no caso usei o **content_main.xml**)
>   com um `FrameLayout` com um `id` ex: `@+id/fragment_container` para
>   que ocorra a transição entre as telas.
>
> Para saber mais, veja o exemplo neste post:
>   [Menu de 3 pontos em todas as Activities com o padrão Navigation Drawer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119551/navigation-drawer-em-todas-as-telas/119561)

---

### Em sua MainActivity - Solução na prática:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // abrindo um novo fragment
     novoFragment fragment = new novoFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTrasaction =
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTrasaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTrasaction.commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery)  {
    // abrindo um nova activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class); 
    startActivity(intent);    
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: insira este código abaixo em seu método onNavigationItemSelected de sua MainActivity??? da nova activity ou da main?
Crie um novo Fragment com o nome de novoFragment e insira este código abaixo em seu método onNavigationItemSelected de sua MainActivity: em qual activity?

Comment: @CarlosDiego em sua MainActivity.java(atividade principal).

Comment: Como faz pra ti chamar no chat?

Comment: Foi sim, nao tem mto tempo.

Comment: Otima dica Paulo

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde,

Tente adicionar

```
.addToBackStack()
```

na transição do fragment.

Tive um problema semelhante, pode ver [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841128/onbackpressed-in-fragment-google-maps)

Espero ter ajudado.

[Edit]

Tente isto

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    if (id == R.id.servic) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new Cronograma())
                .addToBackStack("teste")  //adiciona esta linha
                .commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new Localizacao())
                .addToBackStack(null) //acho que também funciona com null
                .commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new Sobre_aplicativo())
                .addToBackStack("teste2")  //
                .commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
        finish();

    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Marco ainda nao entendi como adicionar .addToBackStack() corretamente no meu codigo.

Comment: depois do replace que você dá no fragmentManager por exemplo : fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new Cronograma()).addToBackStack("Exemplo").commit();

Comment: Certo, desculpa as perguntas, sou novo ainda no android studio... no lugar desse exemplo eu chamo o que?

Comment: Editei a resposta.. só substituir no seu código e testar

Comment: Fiz conforme citou acima, mas continua do mesmo jeito. Uma tela por cima da outra.

Comment: "Porque esta sobrepondo a outra intent e não mudando?"  pelo que vi, você não troca de intent só da um replace no fragment..

Comment: O projeto está no início? Particularmente eu uso esta biblioteca para usar o drawer [link](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer), é estável e flexível...

Comment: Eu apenas estou tentando aproveitar o metodo drawer que o android studio ja implementa ao iniciar um projeto. Acho que ficou meio confuso, reformulando, estou na intent principal e quero ir pro fragment onde estão as opções do menu, porem eu vejo as tuas telas e se eu clicar será respondido pela tela do Main.

Comment: Os fragments vão se sobrepondo ou fica apenas a tela main "embaixo" e encima fica apenas o ultimo fragment?

Comment: Marco fica apenas o ultimo fragment em cima da tela inicial

Comment: Marco qual teu face? ja que nao consigo conversar por chat ainda

Comment: Oi é esse [link](https://www.facebook.com/maarco1993)